# how to post form values as json format using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have form element for some basic information, on submit how to post the form values as json format using jquery?

and how do i test its posted successfully?

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>first name</td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>last name</td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>email</td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>mobile</td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>address</td>
        <td><textarea></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: No, i need to know the step how to do that actually. like am i need to create one empty json file and using ajax post method we need to post the values to that file ?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ & http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [$.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) to perform this task :

```
$("myForm").submit(function(event) {
    /* preventing the submit */
    event.preventDefault();

    var myArray = [];

    /* 
        using myArray.push(value); 
        you can add all the value of yours textboxes to this array.
    */

    var myJsonArray = JSON.parse(myArray);

    $.post("path_to_my_php_file/myfile.php", { json_array : myJsonArray }, function(result) {
        /* this function can eventualy used to process the result of your php */
    });
});
```

If your form send data with `GET` method, use [$.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) function.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the form data in JSON format using ajax, please check below code:

```
var myformData = JSON.stringify($("#your-form-id").serializeArray());

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "ServerURL",
  data: myformData ,
  success: function(){},
  dataType: "json",
  contentType : "application/json"
});
```

Comment: Aftab: in data: what i need to write ?

Comment: you need to replace "#your-form-id" with your form id and "ServerURL" with your server url and just trigger this on click of submit, thats it. Dont forgot to fill the form.

Comment: In the serverURL - am i need to write the html name (form.html ?) or any other json file where it needs to post ?

Comment: I added as like below, is that fine ? i just running in my local how do i test whether the values are posted ?

Comment: <script>
  function submit(){
   var myformData = JSON.stringify($("#sampleForm01").serializeArray());

   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "form01.html",
     data: myformData ,
     success: function(){
    alert("success");
     },
     dataType: "json",
     contentType : "application/json"
   });
  }  
    </script>

Comment: It will not be "form01.html", you need to write the server URL I mean process.php or if you are using asp than process.apsx

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>first name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="firstname" id="fname"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>last name</td>
        <td><input type="text" nmae="lastname" id="lname" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>email</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="email"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>mobile</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="mobile" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>address</td>
        <td><textarea id="address"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Submit" id="buttonClick" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In Jquery add this code:

```
 $("#buttonClick").click(function(){
        var fname,lname,email,mobile,address;
        fname=$("#fname").val();
        lname=$("#lname").val();
        email=$("#email").val();
        mobile=$("#mobile").val();
        address=$("#address").val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"post";
            url:"their write your url for php file ";
            data:"fname="+fname+"&lname="+lname+"&email="+email+"&mobile="+mobile+"&address="+address;
            success:function(res)
            {

            }

        });

    });
at url place your php file where you want to post these values you can get these values by using $_POST['fname'] etc.. in your php file
```

Comment: Junaid: thanks for you code, instead of php file is it possible to create as json format? i.e on submit i need to create the posted values as json format to send for development purpose... also i am trying in my success function:  success:function(res)
    {
     alert(fname);
    } but i am not getting the entered value in alert? anything i missed out?

Comment: you can make javascript object  
var obj={};
        obj['fname']=$("#fname").val();
        obj['lname']=$("#lname").val();
        obj['email']=$("#email").val();
        obj['mobile']=$("#mobile").val();
        obj['address']=$("#address").val();  

then send in data use this   
data: {jsonobj:JSON.stringify(obj)}

Comment: Is this correct?   function submit(){
   var fname,lname,email,mobile,address;
   fname=$("#fname").val();
   lname=$("#lname").val();
   email=$("#email").val();
   mobile=$("#mobile").val();
   address=$("#address").val();
   var obj={}; obj['fname']=$("#fname").val(); obj['lname']=$("#lname").val(); obj['email']=$("#email").val(); obj['mobile']=$("#mobile").val(); obj['address']=$("#address").val();
   $.ajax({
    type:"post";
    url:"sample.json";
    data:"{jsonobj:JSON.stringify(obj)};
    success:function(res)
    {
     alert(fname);
    }
   });
  }

Comment: success alert value when a response get from php file

Comment: how can i ensure its posted successfully ?

Comment: you give url in this url file echo someting  
 in Success function(res){alert(res);}

Comment: res is data which is coming from url file where you post data

Comment: your url is sample.json this should be sample.php because you are posting values to php file their you can get all values using json_decode($_POST['jsonobj']) 
and then echo anything which you can recieve in success function with argument res